# How to use github environment variables within a run command (github actions)

Tags: bash, environment-variables, escaping, github-actions, aws-cli

**Set up:**

- Using Github actions
- One of the steps is using an aws send command to run some scripts on an ec2 instance ([aws
  cli reference here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html))
- The script is just to copy a file from S3 onto the instance
- I have an github environment variable which just have a path set as the
  value

So code looks like this:

```
#setting github env variable
env:
  PATH: C:\


#Script I'm using in my aws cli command
run: |
    aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --parameters 'commands=["Copy-S3Object -BucketName BUCKETNAME -Key FILENAME -LocalFolder \"${{ env.PATH }}\" -Force""]' \
```

This errors with

```
Error Response: "Copy-S3Object : The given path's format is not supported.
```

I can see it is running the commands as:

```
'"Copy-S3Object -BucketName BUCKETNAME -Key FILENAME -LocalFolder \'C:\\' -Force"'
```

So it is reading the slashes that i included to escape the quotation mark. So it think the filepath is literally \'C:\\'

Note: the quotations are needed round the github variable as it couldn't be read when i tried without

**Questions**

Can i not use a github environment within a script?
Any ideas on how to still escape the quotations but not have them show up in the script?

Comment: Does the entire command need to be quoted? Since the previous line ends with a pipe, this indented line should be `Copy-S3Object -BucketName BUCKETNAME -Key FILENAME -LocalFolder "${{ env.PATH }}" -Force` without the enclosing quotes?

Comment: Have you tried `PATH: C:/` ?

Comment: thanks for getting back to be @glennjackman ! yeah sorry i simplified my post but i can see now that has just caused confusion. The aws cli command i'm using would require the quotes. The way to write it is "--parameters 'commands=["echo HelloWorld"]' ". I've updated the post to reflect this now

Comment: have you tried without any escapes ?